# maven error for https://github.com/googleapis/java-translate

Tags: java, api, maven, translation, machine-translation

I am trying to get jar file for using google translation api for java. I downloaded pom.xml from https://github.com/googleapis/java-translate. Then type '`mvn install`' got errors:

```
$ mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Child module D:\googleTranslation\proto-google-cloud-translate-v3beta1 of D:\googleTranslation\pom.xml does not exist @
[ERROR] Child module D:\googleTranslation\proto-google-cloud-translate-v3 of D:\googleTranslation\pom.xml does not exist @
[ERROR] Child module D:\googleTranslation\grpc-google-cloud-translate-v3beta1 of D:\googleTranslation\pom.xml does not exist @
[ERROR] Child module D:\googleTranslation\grpc-google-cloud-translate-v3 of D:\googleTranslation\pom.xml does not exist @
[ERROR] Child module D:\googleTranslation\google-cloud-translate of D:\googleTranslation\pom.xml does not exist @
[ERROR] Child module D:\googleTranslation\google-cloud-translate-bom of D:\googleTranslation\pom.xml does not exist @
```

What I am missing? Any information would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I also edit (not add)    <artifactId>google-cloud-translate</artifactId> to be
        <version>1.94.5</version>. But no difference.